# Symfony 4 findAll with join table

Tags: php, symfony4

I have two tables : `Product` and `Category` with a Relation `ManyToOne`.
Before when i had only `Product` table for `print all product`, i use:

```
$productes = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(Product::class)->findAll();
```

Now,I want print all `product` with their `category`.

How can i do?

Comment: can we see a snippet of your product class property and docblock  for the join ?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this more easily with a dql query. Like this in;

in product repository class

```
public function getAll(){
    $dql = SELECT p, c FROM App\Entity\Product p LEFT JOIN p.category c;
    return $this->getEntityManager()->createQuery($dql)->getResult();
}
```